# Is there a Keyboard Shortcut to Focus on a Known Tabindex

Tags: windows, winforms

When a Windows Form  has the focus you can step through any Controls that have their TabStop Property set True, in Tabindex Order, by pressing the {TAB} Key.

Similarly, you can step through them in reverse order using {Shift+ TAB}

Is there any Keyboard Shortcut to move the Focus to a Known, or Absoulte, Tabindex (for example the Lowest or Highest), rather than moving it Relative to the Active Control?

If so does MS document this anywhere?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's nothing out of the box to do this, AFAIK. You'd need to do it yourself. However, it's not that difficult, you just need to check for a hotkey by overriding the [`ProcessCmdKey`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.containercontrol.processcmdkey) method and then call [`Control.Focus()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.control.focus) for the appropriate control:

```
protected override bool ProcessCmdKey(ref Message msg, Keys keyData)
{
    if (keyData == (Keys.Control | Keys.D1))
    {
        textBox1.Focus();
        return true;
    }
    return base.ProcessCmdKey(ref msg, keyData);
}
```

---

You can even take it a step further to have shortcuts for several controls and also have the ability to manage the controls and their shortcuts at run-time by having a dictionary that holds the shortcuts and the controls to be focused:

```
Dictionary<Keys, Control> FocusShortcuts;

public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    FocusShortcuts = new Dictionary<Keys, Control>();
    FocusShortcuts.Add(Keys.Control | Keys.D1, textBox1);
    FocusShortcuts.Add(Keys.Control | Keys.D2, textBox2);
    FocusShortcuts.Add(Keys.Control | Keys.D3, textBox3);
}

protected override bool ProcessCmdKey(ref Message msg, Keys keyData)
{
    Control control;
    if (FocusShortcuts.TryGetValue(keyData, out control))
    {
        control.Focus();
        return true;
    }
    return base.ProcessCmdKey(ref msg, keyData);
}
```

---

### Update

If instead, you want to set the focus to a control by its Tab Order, you can replace `textBox1.Focus();` with something like this:

```
int someIndex = 5;
Control control = this.Controls.OfType<Control>()
                      .FirstOrDefault(c => c.TabIndex == someIndex);
if (control != null) control.Focus();
```

You'd just need to change the value of `someIndex` to the index of your choice and change `this` with the control's container (you can leave it if the container is the current form/UserControl).

Comment: Thanks Ahmed; I'm assuming this is a solution for C Applications, whereas I was hoping that there may be some native Windows Hotkey combination that would work for any window

Comment: This is a C# code which can easily be translated to other .NET languages like VB.NET. If you're not looking for a _programming solution_, then I'm afraid StackOverflow is not the right place for such a question.

Comment: Also, if you're looking for something that would work on any window of any 3rd party application, how do you expect to specify the "known" or "absolute" control which you wish to be focused?

Comment: I can use something like SendKeys "{TAB}" as a programming solution to Select the Next Control in Tab Order. I was simply asking if there is any such code that would Select ANY KNOWN Control, say the First in Tab Order; I didn't necessarily want to specify which control.

Comment: @mikebinz 1) Using `SendKeys` is a bad idea (especially if called multiple times) because you can't guarantee that your application will be the active window. 2) To my understanding "any _known_ control" means that you _know_ the control (i.e., you can specify it)! 3) If instead, you want to set the focus to a control using its Tab Order, check the updated answer above.

Comment: 1) Agreed, but Desperate Situations sometimes require Desperate Solutions; personally I've got a lot of mileage with SendKeys 2) we went to different English Schools; I would take "a known control" or better still "a specified control" to mean what you take from "any known control"; to me "Any" implies the Choice of All (ie the Union of the Set of) Known Controls 3) thanks the Updated Answer, which gets my vote